# Python Relative path and Absolute path

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pycharm, relative-path, absolute-path

I am using Pycharm to develop my application, I have created a new class, and I use the following method to call this new class:

(Main() to import this class):

```
from src.services.log_service import LogService
```

It works fine in Pycharm, however when I export my code to docker environment, I have the got the following error:
[image]

My dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM python:3.8.6
MAINTAINER tester  tester
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app/src/Main.py"]
```

And my docker directory is as below:
[image]
[image]
[image]

And my folder structure is as below, "log_service.py" is in folder "services"

[image]

I tried to change it to relative path, and Pycharm report error when running again:

```
from .services.log_service import LogService
```

error:

```
    from .services.log_service import LogService
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Should I use relative path or absolute path? Thanks,

Comment: Can you add details on how you're constructing and running the Docker container?  What's the error message you're getting (it shouldn't be an image file, even running Python in Docker)?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I have edit my question and add docker details.